# Practical examples on what 2 Peter 3:16 talks about

Tags: 2-peter

I am working on a message from 2 Peter 3:16 "There are some things in them that are hard to understand, which the ignorant and unstable twist to their own destruction, as they do the other Scriptures.
The Holy Bible: English Standard Version. (2016). (2 Pe 3:16). Wheaton: Standard Bible Society."

I will appreciate some guidance on well known texts which are twisted by Christians to say what they want them to say.

Much appreciated.
Deon

Comment: Posts requesting guidance on some issue or other are usually considered off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically:

> 2 Peter 3:16 "There are some things in them that are hard to
>   understand, which the ignorant and unstable twist to their own
>   destruction, as they do the other Scriptures."

This verse is occasionally used by individuals following the 'Hebrew Roots' movement (among others) to discredit New Testament Theologies based heavily on the letters of Paul. Hermeneutically though, since Peter's text here relates to Paul's letters, this question really should be asking which Pauline letters Peter is referencing - though unfortunately, most answers to such a question are inevitably opinion-based.

This sort of verse could theoretically be used to discredit virtually anything an individual sought to disagree with from Paul's letters. But **we don't have enough information from this text to make any links with any particular Pauline texts** - the text is too vague to render any solid hermeneutical case as to particular applications.